# T-SQL : Loop alternative to reduce exec time

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my 1st post here, glad to be become part of a community I've been following for a long time! I haven't found information on this specific topic despite researches, so here I am.

I'm analyzing transaction data to understand financial margin development, separating different effects such as volume, mix, price, cost etc.
This analysis needs to be done at various levels of granularity, e.g. restricted to a certain geographical scope or a given product category. (80k+ analysis levels possible)

I need to compute those results in one batch to store them into an Excel tool.

To do so:

1. I have a 1st procedure (450 lines with indexes, joins etc) with 10 input variables, returning a single row table containing the output I need for 1 level of analysis (out of the 80k+ mentioned above). It currently takes 45 seconds to run. [working on reducing that time as well - separate problem]
2. I want to estimate this 1st procedure for 80k+ input permutations. I've the 2nd portion of code below which run on a simple input set. However, that would take too long to process all permutations...

> Is there any other approach which would be faster ? Such as considering a join between the possible permutations table and the transaction data ?
>   What would you do to improve performance ?

```
declare @TimeframeVar varchar(55)
declare @EndMonthVar float
declare @EndPeriodVar float
declare @BUVar varchar(55)
...
declare @RegionVar varchar(55)
declare @BranchVar varchar(55)
...
declare @ProductCategoryVar varchar(55)
...

drop table #Variables

Select * 
into #variables 
from xx.Variables


while exists (select top 1 * from #variables)
BEGIN

set @TimeframeVar = ( select top 1 Timeframe from #Variables )
set @EndMonthVar = ( select top 1 EndMonth from #Variables )
set @EndPeriodVar = ( select top 1 EndPeriod from #Variables )
set @BUVar = ( select top 1 BU from #Variables )
...
set @RegionVar = ( select top 1 Region from #Variables )
set @BranchVar = ( select top 1 Branch from #Variables )
...
set @ProductCategoryVar = ( select top 1 ProductCategory from #Variables )
...

exec xx.MarginAnalysis_XX
 @TimeframeVar
,@EndMonthVar
,@EndPeriodVar
,@BUVar
...
,@RegionVar 
,@BranchVar
...
,@ProductCategoryVar
...

Delete from #variables
where Timeframe = @TimeframeVar
  and EndMonth = @EndMonthVar
  and EndPeriod = @EndPeriodVar
  and BU = @BUVar
...
  and region = @RegionVar 
  and Branch = @BranchVar
...
  and productcategory = @ProductCategoryVar
  and ordersize = @OrderSizeVar
...

END
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

EDIT :

**EXPECTED FINAL OUTPUT** (with 80k+ rows)

```
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-----+-------------+
| Granularity | MarginIni | Volume | Price | ... | MarginFinal |
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-----+-------------+
| A           | 100       | +20    | -30   |     | 90          |
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-----+-------------+
| B           | 200       | 150    | -30   |     | 320         |
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-----+-------------+
| C           | ..        | ...    | ...   |     | ...         |
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-----+-------------+
```

**INPUT FROM 1st PROC** (with 1 row)

```
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-----+-------------+
| Granularity | MarginIni | Volume | Price | ... | MarginFinal |
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-----+-------------+
| A           | 100       | +20    | -30   |     | 90          |
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results -- in text table formats -- would really help.

Comment: Sure, just added a quick example. Thanks!